# InfluxDB: Wrong start time when group by more than 1 day

Tags: influxdb

I stuck at one issue related group by when the time interval is more than 1 day. It's giving the wrong start time for different grain when grain is more than 1 day.

---

- Grain = 1day
- ExpectedStartTime=2019-01-01
- ActualStartTime=2019-01-01

```
>  select mean("messages") from rabbitmq where host='rabbitmq_cluster' and time>='2019-01-01 00:00:00' and time<'2019-01-16 00:00:00' GROUP BY time(1d), "host" LIMIT 2;
time                 mean_messages
----                 ----
2019-01-01T00:00:00Z 181232
2019-01-02T00:00:00Z 179728
```

- Grain = 2day
- ExpectedStartTime=2019-01-01
- ActualStartTime=2018-12-31

```
> select mean("messages") from rabbitmq where host='rabbitmq_cluster' and time>='2019-01-01 00:00:00' and time<'2019-01-16 00:00:00' GROUP BY time(2d), "host" LIMIT 2;
time                 mean_messages
----                 ----
2018-12-31T00:00:00Z 181232
2019-01-02T00:00:00Z 347824
```

- Grain = 5day
- ExpectedStartTime=2019-01-01
- ActualStartTime=2018-12-30

```
> select mean("messages") from rabbitmq where host='rabbitmq_cluster' and time>='2019-01-01 00:00:00' and time<'2019-01-16 00:00:00' GROUP BY time(5d), "host" LIMIT 2;
time                 mean_messages
----                 ----
2018-12-30T00:00:00Z 529056
2019-01-04T00:00:00Z 826694.3999999762
```

I read in the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#advanced-group-by-time-syntax) that Influx uses present time boundary, but doesn't say how present time boundary is calculated. Is it a **start of a month** or a **start of a week** or **time of first data received** or **time of the shard starting**?

If I know how this present time boundary is being calculated, I can specify offset in groupby to keep the first slot starting from 2019-01-01.

Answer (score 2):

InfluxDB uses epoch time to calculate the present time boundaries. It creates groupby slots with reference to epoch time.

To keep start time same in groupby I need to pass an offset.

Here is a simple offset calculation function written in python which takes start time and groupby interval.

```
def get_offset(start_dt, interval_m):
    epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    offset = (start_time - epoch).total_seconds() % (interval_m * 60)
    return offset

start_dt = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1,0,0)
interval_m = 1440 * 3 # 3 days 
offset_s = get_offset(start_dt, interval_m) # 172800
```

Groupby interval with **3 days**, the query will look like below with offset.

```
> select mean("messages") from rabbitmq where host='rabbitmq_cluster' and time>='2019-01-01 00:00:00' and time<'2019-01-16 00:00:00' GROUP BY time(3d, 172800s), "host" LIMIT 2;
time                      mean_messages
----                      ----
2019-01-01T00:00:00+05:30 539232
2019-01-04T00:00:00+05:30 464640
```

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8010

Comment: Very clever. Any idea how to make this in php?

Comment: you just need to write get_offset function in php to generate offset for influx query

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer - very helpful! You do have a small typo in the get_offset() function, where in the `offset = ` line the variable reference should be to `start_dt` rather than `start_time`.

I tried to submit an edit suggestion, but was rejected since apparently "Edits must be at least 6 characters"...hah